# Invoke pstools in Python script

Tags: python, sysinternals

I am trying to invoke pstools (specifically, psloggedon.exe) in my Python script

```
import sys, subprocess, socket, string
import wmi, win32api, win32con

pst = subprocess.Popen(
        ["D:\pstools\psloggedon.exe", "-l", "-x", "\\10.10.10.10"],
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr = subprocess.PIPE
    )

out, error = pst.communicate()

print pst, "is output"
```

This is the output

```
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x0000000002B18D68> is output
```

I would like the output to be

```
DOMAIN\user
```

Thank You

Comment: try 'print out' instead of 'print pst'

Comment: @pss -- this solved my problem. However, I have new question that I posted here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686333/python-script-not-executing-sysinternals-command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print the output then you have to use `print out, "is output"` instead of `print pst, "is output"`  because `out` will contain the output.