# Python script not executing sysinternals command

Tags: python, subprocess, sysinternals

This is a follow-up from [Invoke pstools in Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23685675/invoke-pstools-in-python-script)

When I open a command prompt and execute

```
D:\pstools\psloggedon.exe -l -x \\10.10.10.10
```

I get

```
DOMAIN\user
```

But when I execute the script

```
import sys, subprocess, socket, string
import wmi, win32api, win32con



pst = subprocess.Popen(
        ["D:\pstools\psloggedon.exe", "-l", "-x", "\\10.10.10.10"],
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr = subprocess.PIPE
    )

out, error = pst.communicate()


print out, "is output"
```

I get

```
Error opening HKEY_USERS for \10.10.10.10
is output
```

How do I get the subprocess to read the IP address as \10.10.10.10 instead of \10.10.10.10

By the way, I tried to add third backslash

```
pst = subprocess.Popen(
        ["D:\pstools\psloggedon.exe", "-l", "-x", "\\\10.10.10.10"],
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr = subprocess.PIPE
    )
```

And the output is

```
Error opening HKEY_USERS for .0.139.40
is output
```

Comment: shouldn't there **four** backslashes? You want to have "\\" so you need to escape **both** of them.

Comment: @lejlot --- this solved my problem. Can you click "Answer Question" so I can mark it as the answer

Comment: I suggest using [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) in the future e.g. `r"\\\10.10.10.10"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by  lejlot's comment you have to use "\\" because "\" is an escape character in python.