# Parse variable in python subprocess

Tags: python, string, subprocess, sysinternals

This is follow on from [Python script not executing sysinternals command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686333/python-script-not-executing-sysinternals-command)

My script takes input

```
python ps.py sender-ip=10.10.10.10
```

The sender-ip gets read into a variable, userIP. However, when I pass userIP into the following subprocess

```
pst = subprocess.Popen(
        ["D:\pstools\psloggedon.exe", "-l", "-x", "\\\\", userIP],
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr = subprocess.PIPE
    )

out, error = pst.communicate()

userLoggedOn = out.split('\n')[1].strip()
print 'userId={}'.format(userloggedon)
```

The script will output

```
userId=
```

How do I make the subprocess read the userIP so it will execute

```
D:\pstools\psloggedon.exe  -l -x \\userIP
```

And output

```
userId=DOMAIN\user
```

EDIT

Command-line to execute the script is

```
python py.ps sender-ip=10.10.10.10
```

When I manually execute

```
D:\PSTools\PsLoggedon.exe -l -x \\10.10.10.10
```

I get the result I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'\\\\'` and `userIP` are not separate options, but you pass it as if they were separate to psloggedon.exe.

Glue them into one string:

```
userIP="\\\\"+userIP
pst = subprocess.Popen(
        ["D:\pstools\psloggedon.exe", "-l", "-x",  userIP],
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr = subprocess.PIPE
    )
```

Check out your print statement also. You set `userLoggedOn` variable, and then print using `userloggedon`.

Comment: I copied and pasted this code and it still doesn't work. userId is blank again

Comment: @Glowie Watch the backslashes escaping, the executable is probably not found, see my answer above

Comment: @JanVlcinsky --- I just tried executing  D:\PSTools\PsLoggedon.exe -l -x \\10.10.10.10 manually and it works .... Your solution looks correct, I cannot figure why it's not working ....

Comment: @GMGray --- see EDIT in original post

Comment: @Glowie - userloggedon and userLoggedOn are different variables.. which one are you trying to print out? check out your `print` statement.

Comment: use raw string literals for Windows paths, to avoid [bugs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23686333/4279).

Answer (score 1):

Your trouble is in name of executable. Single backslash works just as escape character, so if you would print name of the command you are going to start, you would see the backslashes being lost.

The options are:

```
cmd = r"D:\pstools\psloggedon.exe" # raw string prefix r
print cmd
cmd = "D:\\pstools\\psloggedon.exe" # double backslash
print cmd
cmd = "D:/pstools/psloggedon.exe" # forward slash works also on windows
print cmd
```

You may try using following idiom, which allows better detection of problems

```
userIP="\\\\"+userIP

cmd = ["D:\\pstools\\psloggedon.exe"]
cmd.extend(["-l", "-x", userIP])
print "cmd", cmd # do it only, if you are developing
pst = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd,
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr = subprocess.PIPE
    )
```

This allows you to print out `cmd` and see, if there are possible problems visible.

note: the code above builds on the accepted answer solution (which adds solution for proper `userIP` but might have problems with backslashes).

Comment: if I hardcode the IP address, it works, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686333/python-script-not-executing-sysinternals-command, how will this work for including a variable?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to make it work is to use raw-string literal to avoid escaping backslashes inside string literals and to pass the command as a string on Windows:

```
from subprocess import check_output

output = check_output(r"D:\pstools\psloggedon.exe  -l -x \\userIP")
print(output.splitlines())
```